RewriteCond/RewriteRule mod_rewrite apache Stripping query string except from specific URL
I'm trying to use RewriteCond and RewriteRule to strip a query string from all URLs on a site except for those in a specific URL. The problem I'm having is with the multiple conditionals that are required to combine the EXCEPT part that's required.
This is what I have currently. I'd like to strip the start= query string from all URLs EXCEPT those that contain /resources/blog:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/resources/blog
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^start=\d+$
RewriteRule (.*)       /$1?    [L,R=301,QSD]

However, for URLs that don't include /resources/blog, the conditional fails, so it immediately processes the RewriteRule and applies it to all URLs.
I only want the rewrite rule above to apply to URLs that don't involve our blog. How do I write the logic such that it applies to every URL EXCEPT those I specify?
